# Jquery UI AutoComplete Sending extra dynamic parameters to ashx

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to pass extra parameters through to my ashx when using Jquery UI auto complete. 
I have seen lots of examples and have spent ages fiddling but I can't get mine to work.

I have two auto complete textboxes, what ever is entered in the first one needs to narrow down the search for the second one.

On my first autocomplete textbox all works fine and the ID that is returned is set to a hidden field.

```
 $("#<%=txtSearch1.ClientID%>").autocomplete('/Search1.ashx');
    $('#<%=txtSearch1.ClientID%>').result(function (event, data, formatted)
    {
        if (data) {
            var id = data[1];
            $("#<%=hdnSearched1.ClientID%>").val(id);
        }
    });
```

I want to use the value of the hidden field along with the value the user enters into the second textbox to do the search for the second auto complete

I first tried this:

```
    $("#<%=txtSearch2.ClientID%>").autocomplete('/Search2.ashx',{
   extraParams: { "Id": $("#<%=hdnSearched1.ClientID%>").val() }});
```

This fired my ashx but the Id in the extraparams was blank. A bit of googling told me this was because it was set when the page loaded so the value for the extra param was set before I set the value of the hidden field.

I did a bit more fiddling and searching and came up with something like this which a lot of people seem to be using.

```
    $('#<%=this.txtSearch2.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Search2.ashx',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    sId: $("#<%=hdnSearched1.ClientID%>").val()
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }                 
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem is this doesn't even fire the ashx! I have been fiddling about with this for ages, following example after example but I can't seem to work what I am doing wrong!
I'm sure it must be obvious!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean the "source" callback does not get executed or an error is directly returned when using $.ajax ? In that case, check the console to see the error.

Comment: The source doesn't get executed (or at least doesn't appear to) and I get no errors or values back

Comment: Is the javascript code inside the html or as an external javascript file ?

Comment: it is in the aspx page, so not not as external file

Comment: Well, the code seems ok to me. Put an alert before the ajax call, also check the console for any ajax error.